# How to get the largest element index in matlab array

Tags: matlab, max, octave

Here is a simple double array:

```
array=[3 1 1]
```

Largest element index is 1

or:

```
array=[3 9 1]
```

Largest element index is 2

How can I get the largest element index?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use the second output argument of the `max` function:

```
[ max_value, max_index ] = max( [ 3 9 1 ] )
```

Answer (score 3):

My standard solution is to do

```
index = find(array == max(array), 1);
```

which returns the index of the first element that is equal to the maximum value. You can fiddle with the options of `find` if you want the last element instead, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the max value of each row you can use:

```
array = [1, 2, 3; 6, 2, 1; 4, 1, 5];
[max_value max_index] = max(array, [], 2)

%3, 3
%6, 1
%5, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In Octave If
A =
   1   3   2
   6   5   4
   7   9   8

1) For Each Column Max value and corresponding index of them can be found by
>> [max_values,indices] =max(A,[],1)
max_values =
   7   9   8
indices =
   3   3   3


2) For Each Row Max value and corresponding index of them can be found by
>> [max_values,indices] =max(A,[],2)
max_values =
   3
   6
   9
indices =
   2
   1
   2

Similarly For minimum value

>> [min_values,indices] =min(A,[],1)
min_values =
   1   3   2

indices =
   1   1   1

>> [min_values,indices] =min(A,[],2)
min_values =
   1
   4
   7

indices =
   1
   3
   1
```